# Write Conflict error in MS Access 2010 when i try to assign a record source

Tags: ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 linked tables in my MS Access 2010.

I have many forms in this MS Access database. Few of my forms gets Write Conflict error when I try to assign it to a SQL statement as record source after I have updated very same record by SQL statement (or assign some values on form programmatically and refreshed the form in module) as I have general function being called every time I enter certain text on one of the field on form and it gets updated some of the forms fields value programmatically.

I have a TIMESTAMP column in my table in SQL Server.

So after updating the fields on the forms, when I try to assign a new record like
`Me.Recordsouce = sqlstring` , I get a "write conflict" error.

I tried to set on button click before I assign a recordsource

Refresh

```
Docmd.RunCommand AcCmdSaveRecord
```

But they all throw the same "Write Conflict" error and asking me to drop changes.

Please help
Many thanks,

Comment: [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] because it is unclear what your specific problem is. Also, make sure you make it clear what is error output and what is your explanation.

Comment: This issue has been resolved.